# Same name, same class, totally different products

Tags: united-states, software, trademark

Let's assume the following situation:

- A company X produces devices used in some niche industry. It has a US trademark Z registered in IC9 category (class 9).
- A company Y creates and sells a software named Z in a B2C market. It wants to register a US trademark Z in IC9 category (class 9).

Can company Y register a trademark? Can the company X sue company Y for using the same name in a different market (with or without a registration)?

Comment: @ColleenV please don’t answer in comments

Comment: @DaleM That wasn't an answer by any stretch of the guidelines for an answer anywhere on the Stack Exchange network. That was a link to a relevant resource that anyone could find with simple Google search offered with no explanation of how it would be applied to this question. The text in quotes was an excerpt from the link. If I had posted that as an answer, it should have be deleted as "low quality". See https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/link-only-answers/info

Comment: @ColleenV Please return the link :)

Comment: @ColleenV I refer you to When shouldn’t I comment? I accept your comment would have been “low quality” but it’s still an answer and we don’t answer in comments. Write a good answer or move along without writing a bad one in the comments. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment